# create 2 ul's with max 10 li's from ajax callback in loop

Tags: jquery, html-lists, each

I get returned from the server more than 50 items in my xml response. I know it would be better to handle on the server but this is a request:

Make 2 lists with open `<ul>` and closing `<\ul>` each of them has 10 items from the response. No ordering just counting from beginning.

My loop now look like this:

```
var strHtml = '<ul>';
$(xml).find('Books row').each(function()
{
   strHtml += '<li><a href ="mylink">sometext</a></li>';
   // ...
});
strHtml += '<\ul>';
$('#category').empty().append(strHtml);
```

What i need is 2 lists, so i have to handle open and close UL tag in the loop. 
Something like this, but i'm not sure if i'm doin it allright:

```
var itemCounter = 1,
    strHtml ='';

    $(xml).find('Books row').each(function()    //note: function( index )
    {
       if (itemCounter  == 1){
         // first iteration opens <ul>
         strHtml += '<ul>'; 
       }
       else if(itemCounter > 10){
         // 10th list item created. 
         // close first UL and open next UL
          strHtml += '</ul><ul>';
       }
       else if(itemCounter > 20){
         // max items allowed detected
         // close <ul> and break loop
         strHtml += '</ul>';
         return;
       }

       // regular li
       strHtml += '<li><a href ="mylink">sometext</a></li>';
       itemCounter++;

    });
    $('#category').empty().append(strHtml);
```

How would you handle this?

sidenote:

my html/css structure needs to have 2 vertical side by side lists. I found the best result to be in two  and float them left, instead of having one  list and floating every single item.

Comment: What does your XML look like? Link it, don't post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that opening and closing and checking the counter stuff seems a bit fiddly, and also this line:

```
else if(itemCounter > 10){
```

will be true every time once the counter is above `10` so it'll never go into the final `else if` block.

I'd put all the li elements into a single array and then just [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) out of the array and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var lis = [];
$(xml).find('Books row').each(function(){
   lis.push('<li><a href ="mylink">sometext</a></li>');
   if (lis.length === 20)
      return false; // break out of .each()
});

var $cat = $("#category").empty();
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i += 10)
    $cat.append('<ul>' + lis.slice(i,i+10).join("") + '</ul>');
​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nRtmj/1/

Note that because I've done the `.slice()` and `.join()` in a loop you can easily create additional ul elements if you change the first loop so that it doesn't stop at 20 elements: http://jsfiddle.net/nRtmj/2/ or if you want to change the number of elements per list just change the `10` to something else: http://jsfiddle.net/nRtmj/3/

Comment: i know it was late and wrote that snippet a bit fast,..but it represented my problem. And i got a very good response. Thanks a lot